# Swagger UI too slow

Tags: performance, swagger, swagger-ui

Recently I am working with Swagger UI to make an API Explorer. The problem is, when I have a lot of data, the UI takes a long time to respond to any interaction (even if I select any text, or enter data into a textfield).

Do you know why and have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the latest swagger-ui?

Comment: Please anyone with a Solution yet?

Comment: Using SwashBuckle with version 5.4 and facing same issue. It seems to be something to do when more end points or tables are added in there.